# Why i am getting this error "EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent cannot be resolved to a type"?

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can i resolve this error in spring boot?

I am trying to get the port number and host-name but continuously i am getting this error.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RegistrationFormApplication implements ApplicationListener<EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent> {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegistrationFormApplication.class, args);
    }
    Logger logger;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent embeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent) {
        logger.info("Port " + embeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent.getApplicationContext().getEmbeddedServletContainer().getPort());
        try {
           logger.info("HOST Address " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
            logger.info("Host Name " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the spring-boot log where the error is displayed

Comment: What are your `import` statements ?

Comment: This is the import:

Comment: import java.net.InetAddress;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment

Comment: Are you by chance getting this when running in Eclipse?  If so, have you tried running at the command line?  I was curious because I don't recall ever seeing that error message in all my many years working with Java, so I googled for this error.  It seems to come up mostly for eclipse users.

Comment: @Khushi are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: but even if i add the import statement for this class  its not resolved.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam i am using maven

Comment: This isn't the standard error you get when a type is undeclared.  It's something more devious going on.

Comment: @Khushi post your `pom.xml`

Comment: @Steve what should i do then? and how can i fix it?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingamnot able to add the pom file .

Comment: @Khushi.  If you are using Eclipse, google for "cannot be resolved to a type" and you'll see lots of questions and answers about this particular error.  There will probably be advice you can use there.  I don't use Eclipse, so I've never seen this problem and am not sure what exactly to do about it.  I doubt it's completely exclusive to eclipse, but I think its significant that the whole first page of google results involve Eclipse specifically it seems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably because you copy/pasted some code that was written for Spring Boot 1.x while you are using Spring Boot 2.x where this class has been removed.

Try using `ServletWebServerInitializedEvent` and `port = event.getWebServer().getPort()`.

See https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2018/07/spring-boot-get-port-of-spring-boot.html for different ways to get the server port.

Comment: @Steve OP never mentioned it a Runtime error or Compile time error

Comment: Anyway, the OP is probably a beginner and needs to learn that frameworks change over time and that mentioning version in a question is probably a good idea. Nor to mention that the OP did not say how this project was created, using Spring CLI would also be a good idea.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Yes, i am new with Spring-boot and Thank you ! The provided reference works well .